# Cant configure MVC 4 SqlMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, sqlmembershipprovider

I am setting up my MVC 4 website to use SqlMembershipProvider with data store as SQL Server Express 11.0.21xx

I have installed Universal Providers via NuGet
`PM > Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers`

When I run the app and go to localhost/Accounts/Register and submit the form, I get this error
`To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".`

at this line
`WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);`

Accounts controller has attribute `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` set. But the tables are not created due to aforementioned error.

web.config section updated by NuGet
`<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">

      <providers>

        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
             applicationName="/" />

      </providers>

    </profile>

    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">

      <providers>

        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"

             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"

             enablePasswordReset="true"

             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"

             requiresUniqueEmail="false"

             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"

             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"

             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"

             passwordAttemptWindow="10"

             applicationName="/" />

      </providers>

    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">

      <providers>

        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider"

             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
             applicationName="/" />

      </providers>

    </roleManager>

    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">

      <providers>

        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />

      </providers>

    </sessionState>`

ConnectionString
`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=servername\instance;Database=imdb;User Id=sa; Password=passbird;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Where's the problem? Should I use universal providers at all? I dont believe I should run aspnet_regsql cos of the new Account controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was change DefaultMembershipProvider to SimpleMembershipProvider in web.config. **type** attribute is important to get it right.

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
         type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" 
         connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" 
         type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" 
         connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```